# Roslyn cannot read the semantic model of the external API

Tags: roslyn

When my project is missing some dependencies, roslyn is unable to read the semantic model of these APIs.
For example: uninstalling the newtonsoft.json dependency, when parsing the
`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);` statement, it cannot return its semantic model.

How can I programmatically load the required dependencies? Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Can you not add the dependency to the compilation? It's unclear *why* the dependency is missing - please add more information to your question.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically add dependencies programmatically? The missing dependencies may be because of the project obtained by decompiling the dll files with ilspy.

Comment: Yes, you'd add them to the Compilation. But again, you should add more information to the question. We have no idea what your code looks like at the moment.